# DJANGO - Redirect to different page with form data

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi i want to redirect to a destination page with the from data. For example when user fills a form the data inputted in the form, i want that to be outputted on the destination page
my codes are as follows:-

source page(experiment.html), I am unsure what the action should be for the form so please help me with it

```
<form action="{% url 'lazer.views.about_experiment' exp.link_name %}" method="POST"> 
  {% csrf_token %}
      <label>Researcher Name(s):<input type="text" name="researcher">
    <lable>Study Summary<textarea rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="here you go" maxlength="500" class="form-control" name="study"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
```

destination page (about_experiment.html)

```
<h3>Holding page for {{ exp.name }}.</h3>
<h2> {{ form }} </h2>
```

views.py

```
from .forms import AboutHelp
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def about_experiment(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AboutHelp(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        researcher = form.cleaned_data['researcher']
        study = form.cleaned_data['study']

else:
    form = AboutHelp()
return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'form': form})`
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class AboutHelp(forms.Form):
    researcher  = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    study = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^about/(?P<ex_link_name>\w+)', lazer.views.about_experiment, name='lazer.views.about_experiment'),
```

Comment: You are pointing to a view called `about_experiment` but it doesn't exist.

Comment: could you help me with the required changes

Comment: Start by changing `get_name` for `about_experiment` in `views.py`, that way when you submit the form in `about_experiment.html` the request will be processed by `about_experiment`, as you wrote it in your `urls.py`.

Comment: so you mean i should change the name get_name to about_experiment right? i did that but then error is coming after i submit the form "about_experiment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ex_link_name'"

Comment: In the form action you don't pass parameters (they go in the request post), so you can delete `exp.link_name`.